# Android Emulator is not running on Android Studio 3.3.2 (MacBook Air)

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have installed Android Studio 3.3.2, I had some problems with the SDK path and I cannot run the app from my application icon, but from the terminal window using sudo ./studio. I had to set the SDK path and re-install SDK into a new folder.

Now I cannot run the AVD emulator and I get the following error messages:

```
18:23   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name 
[Pixel_2_XL_API_28], use -list-avds to see valid list.

18:23   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have been through all the other fixes, such as re-installing Android Studio, re-installing the emulation, Intel x86 Emulator accelerator enabled, deleting all the virtual devices and re-building them.

There is one problem, which is my MacBook keeps reporting "Your disk is almost full" currently have 1.5GB spare space on the drive.

I have been through all the other fixes, such as re-installing Android Studio, re-installing the emulation, Intel x86 Emulator accelerator enabled, deleting all the virtual devices and re-building them.

I have read the path might be set wrong for the AVD drivers, but cannot see anywhere these are present in the Android Studio.

Could the problem be with the lack of space disk space or something else going?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-built by MacBook and re-installed Android Studio and all problems resolved.